# Downloading a file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel, I have a page in which I am trying to provide download links to files and I am using Laravel Filemananager to upload these files.

The path to these files is set in the `lfm.php` config file as:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Working Directory
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

// Which folder to store files in project, fill in 'public', 'resources', 'storage' and so on.
// You should create routes to serve images if it is not set to public.
'base_directory' => 'public',

'images_folder_name' => 'assets/uploads/images',
'files_folder_name'  => 'storage/files',

'shared_folder_name' => 'shares',
'thumb_folder_name'  => 'thumbs',
```

I followed the documentation on the Laravel website regarding the `public` and `storage` folders which says the following:

> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly
>   accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and
>   stores these files in  **storage/app/public**. To make them accessible
>   from the web, you should **create a symbolic link** from **public/storage** to
>   **storage/app/public**.
>
> This convention will keep your publicly accessible
>   files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments
>   when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.
>
> To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan
>   command:
>
> **php artisan storage:link**

Before anything else I also set the following:

1. In my `.env` I changed the app URL to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000` which is where `php artisan server` spins up a local server.
2. In `filesystems.php` I changed the public array to the following:

   `'public' => [
       'driver' => 'local',
       'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
       'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
       'visibility' => 'public',
   ],`

I then created the SymLink.

In my public directory I then had the below:

[image]

Which is a link to `storage/app/public`

Then I uploaded a file to `shares`, so in my `storage` folder I now had:

`app/public/shares/name-of-file`

To test this I have the following Controller and View:

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class TemplateController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $files = Storage::allFiles('files/shares');

        return view('pages.templates-and-tools.index', compact('files'));
    }
}
```

**Relevant part in view**

```
<table id="templates" class=" table-striped table-vaccancies table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">Type</th>
            <th class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">Name</th>
            <th class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">Category</th>
            <th class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">Modified</th>
            <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">Size</th>

        </tr>
        <tr class="warning no-result">
            <td colspan="5">
                <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
                <h3 class="text-center"> No result</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


        @foreach ($files as $file) 
        @php 


        $date = Storage::lastModified($file); $date = gmdate("d/m/Y - H:i", $date); 
        $size = Storage::size($file); $size = ceil ($size/1000); 
        $url = Storage::url($file);

        $fileName = pathinfo($file)['filename']; 
        $Category = pathinfo($file)['dirname']; 
        $type = pathinfo($file)['extension'];
        $Category = basename(dirname( $file)) 
        @endphp

        <tr>
            <td>{{$type}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ Storage::download($url) }} ">{{$fileName }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{$Category}}</td>
            <td> {{$date}}</td>
            <td>{{$size}}kb</td>
        </tr>


        @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>
```

The above grabs everything in the Storage folder under `files/shares`, I then just spit out a bunch of information about the file into each table cell.

The issue I'm facing is with this line:

`<a href="{{ Storage::download($url) }}">{{$fileName }}</a>`

It returns the following error:

`File not found at path: http:/127.0.0.1:8000/storage/files/shares/Hummingbird_Technologies_ES.pdf (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\my-newable\resources\views\pages\templates-and-tools\index.blade.php)`

Which is a pretty straightforward error, but...

[image]

You can see that the file exists.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/access-file-in-symbolic-link-folder-publicstorage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, check your file is uploaded successfully.

And then specific url added in `a` tag `download` parameter. Like this.

`<a href="{{ Storage::url($path) }}" download>{{$fileName }}</a>`

Or added download url in your `a` tag. Like this.

`<a href="{{ route('download_url',$path) }}">Download</a>`

Controller.

```
 public function download($path)
 {
     return Storage::download($path);
 }
```

Comment: Why using 'Storage::url($path)' the file is dowloaded with .html extension?